# Php - Upload doc, docx, pdf - extract all content

Tags: php, pdf, extract, docx, doc

- is there anyway to perform OCR while uploading a document?
- can we index the entire document?
- can the search engine index the entire document? Even though users are required to pay to view the full document?
- can the document be displayed as a preview with only the selected excerpt visible and the rest blurry with the format of the document still viewable?

I've been trying to find easy solutions to these questions using simple php functions or something that wouldn't seem like rocket science to accomplish. But everywhere I look I see people talking about ApachePOI and Solr Cell and all these server commands that I have no idea about. For the last question, i could only figure out that we can use PHPGD and generate images with blurred content, but I wasnt sure how to make that work if there was formatted text, images and tables etc in the document.

So if someone has easy solutions, or even complicated solutions buts with EASY instructions, those will do. Something like "php document content extraction for noobs", that will start from the a-b-c's of it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There's way too much to cover in a single question here. You should ask a separate question for each separate part of this.

Comment: Isn't there a signle solution that will cater to all the needs? Like a simple comtent extraction technique that will do it all? Except for the last question ofcourse, but that isn't the main problem here and can be ignored

Comment: No. You'll be lucky to find a lib that covers more than one of these at once, especially since you're asking about multiple document formats.

Comment: I'm hoping someone who has done this before comes across this question, as they'll easily just point me to resources or tutorials that will cover all of them. Or atleast point me in the right direction.

Comment: Don't hold your breath. You're talking about parsing multiple proprietary document formats, performing optical character recognition on vector formats (e.g. PDF), indexing algorithms, search algorithms and complex image processing. A very big ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend_Search_Lucene contains some code to read the docx file, which will run in PHP alone.

For PDF and doc, you can use command line utilities to extract the plain text content, such as catdoc or pdftotext. You can find such utilities for most file formats out there if you search around. They are usually packaged by most distributions.

From the raw text format, you can feed it to any full text search engine.

Answer (score 0):

> - is there anyway to perform OCR while uploading a document?

Sure, OCR works on any image data. OCR components do exists, just use one.

> - can we index the entire document?

I can not tell you if "we" can, but I can index documents. You just need a document, an index and a routine to index the document.

> - can the search engine index the entire document? Even though users are required to pay to view the full document?

That depends on the document format. If a document is protected and the indexer is not able to access it in full, then it can not index it in full. On the other hand, if the index is able to circumvent the protection, it can index it anyway but that might be legally questionable in some areas of law. Technically this should not be an issue.

> - can the document be displayed as a preview with only the selected excerpt visible and the rest blurry with the format of the document still viewable?

Why not? I mean if you have such kind of display routine doing so, what's the deal?

If it's your problem that you're not familiar with the technologies used, I suggest you get in contact with someone who is familiar and can explain it to you. For some tasks components should exist, however, it's you who needs to bring those together. Your question covers too much so that there is a solution out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Polynomial is correct.  You are not going to find this all in the one place.  Even the OCR is going to require multiple modules to get working correctly and none of that is going to be totally free.  If you want reasonable OCR then you will need to use a commercial engine.

You will need a Word DOC/DOCX To TIFF converter along with a PDF to TIFF converter or you will need to buy something like ABBYY FineReader SDK to perform the OCR which will not cheap but will certainly do a much better job than Tesseract OCR.

The indexing and searching is probably the easy bit using ApachePOI and Solr Cell but the blurred preview will require some custom coding.

This project will not be easy or cheap.

Comment: For Word Doc/Docx to Tiff the http://www.convertapi.com could be used. Just note for @Hakre.